# How to convert ArrayList or String Array into String formate?

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I am working on ArrayList & String Array.I need this Array in below format.

["abc","xyz,"pqr"]

My code snippet is as per below.

```
        ArrayList<String> backList=new ArrayList<String>();

        backList.add("abc");
        backList.add("xyz");
        backList.add("pqr");

        String blist[]=new String[100];
        for(int i=0;i<backList.size();i++){
            blist[i]=backList.get(i);
        }
        Log.e("Log","Array in String="+blist.toString());
```

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Comment: show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @darpan I got answer.i solved above question using jsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use List.toArray():

```
List<String> backList = new ArrayList<>();
backList.add("abc");
backList.add("xyz");
backList.add("pqr");
String[] blist = backList.toArray(new String[backList.size()]);
```

And use Arrays.toString() to print it:

```
Log.e("Log","Array in String=" + Arrays.toString(blist));
```

Answer (score 0):

First store String data into JSONArray.

After convert it into String.

```
JSONArray backArray=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<backList.size();i++){
    backArray.put(backList.get(i));
}
Log.e("Log","String Formate Array="+backArray.toString());
```